# Struts2-jquery-plugin runtime problem

Tags: jquery, struts2

Hi I'm using struts 2 with JQuery plugin (http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/). I'm trying to load a target div, i have load the jar, i've put the tag :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

`<sj:head/>` in the head,

this is the script

```
<s:url id="ajaxTest" value="listDossier.action"/> 
    <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="div1"> 
      Update Content 
    </sj:a> 

    <div id="div1">

   </div>
```

but the script don't run, i can't load the page.
How can i do?

I'm Using SITEMESH

IT, Guido

Answer (score 2):

Use `<sj:div>` in place of `<div>` also if you could post your jsp then it would be helpful.